# Struct members alignment in Visual C++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, struct, memory-alignment

Visual C++ let's you select the struct members alignemnt in the project's properties page. Problem is, this configuration is being used for all srtructs in the project.

Is there any way (VC++ specific, I'd guess) to set a certain struct's member alignment individually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#pragma pack
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(VS.80).aspx

Comment: No, gcc also has it http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Comment: #pragmas are never standard as they are defined to be implementation-defined. However, GCC also supports them: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Answer (score 1):

[#pragma pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

for really specific structure alignments you can fiddle with padding bytes

So add a few dummy bytes between the various fields, until the alignment fits with your needs.

example:

struct example
{
    unsigned short x;
    byte dummy1;
    byte dummy2;
    byte dummy3;
    byte dummy4;
    byte dummy5;
    byte dummy6;
    unsigned int y;
};

if the dummy bytes wouldn't have been placed, the int would probably have been places on offset 4 (4 bytes from the beginning of the struct, while now it has been placed at offset 8)

waring: very compiler specific, and bad code practice ;^)